# Populate form using jinga2 / flask html with button dynamic

Tags: jquery, python, html, flask

I'm trying to populate a form, by clicking in data from table, but I'm trying do it so dynamically that only get the last value, in this case it's stopping in column 3.
I can't find a way to do it directly with html / a href, so I'm trying with jquery.
Any help would be fantastic :)

the list:

```
{% set my_list = [
   {'field_1': 'James', 'field_2': 'Breakfast', 'field_3': '8', 'field_4': 'Bacon', 'field_5': 'and', 'field_6': 'some', 'field_7': 'Eggs'},
   {'field_1': 'Amy', 'field_2': 'Lunch', 'field_3': '13', 'field_4': 'Big', 'field_5': 'salad', 'field_6': 'with', 'field_7': 'nuts'},
   {'field_1': 'Peter', 'field_2': 'Breakfast', 'field_3': '9', 'field_4': 'Fruit', 'field_5': 'and', 'field_6': 'some', 'field_7': 'Cereals'}
] %}
```

the table:

```
<table>
  <caption>Magestic Table</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>field_1</th>
      <th>field_2</th>
      <th>field_3</th>
      <th>field_4</th>
      <th>field_5</th>
      <th>field_6</th>
      <th>field_7</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for x in my_list %}
    <tr>
      <td><a href="#" class="list_details_1_{{ x.field_1[:3] }} btn btn-default btn-xs btn-sm">{{ x.field_1 }} | {{ x.field_3 }}</a></td>
      <td><a href="#" class="list_details_2_{{ x.field_1[:3] }} btn btn-info btn-xs btn-sm">{{ x.field_2 }}</a></td>
      <td><a href="#" class="list_details_3_{{ x.field_1[:3] }} btn btn-success btn-xs btn-sm">{{ x.field_3 }}</a></td>
      <td><a href="#" class="list_details_4_{{ x.field_1[:3] }} btn btn-info btn-xs btn-sm">{{ x.field_4 }}<br>{{ x.field_1 }}</a></td>
      <td><a href="#" class="list_details_5_{{ x.field_1[:3] }} btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-sm">{{ x.field_5 }}</a></td>
      <td><a href="#" class="list_details_6_{{ x.field_1[:3] }} btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-sm">{{ x.field_2 }} <b>or</b> {{ x.field_6 }}</a></td>
      <td><a href="#" class="list_details_7_{{ x.field_1[:3] }} btn btn-warning btn-xs btn-sm">{{ x.field_7 }}</a></td>
    </tr>
    <script>
      $(".list_details_1_{{ x.field_1[:3] }}").click(function(){
      $(".form-control-field_1").val({{ x.field_1 }});
      $(".form-control-field_3").val({{ x.field_3 }});
      });
      $(".list_details_2_{{ x.field_1[:3] }}").click(function(){
      $(".form-control-field_1").val({{ x.field_2 }});
      });
      $(".list_details_3_{{ x.field_1[:3] }}").click(function(){
      $(".form-control-field_3").val({{ x.field_3 }});
      });
    </script>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

the form:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">Populate Here</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <form action="{{url_for('login')}}" method="post" class="form-inline" id="list_form">
        <input type="text" class="form-control-field_1" placeholder="Field 1" name="field_1" id="field_1" value="{{request.form.field_1 }}">
        <input type="text" class="form-control-field_2" placeholder="Field 2" name="field_2" id="field_2" value="{{request.form.field_2 }}">
        <input type="text" class="form-control-field_3" placeholder="Field 3" name="field_3" id="field_3" value="{{request.form.field_3 }}">
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize later that I already give the right solution for this case, while I was building this "test case", by renaming with the column name (field...).

Just missing to do the same for all the remaining ones, and create their respective function to activate them.

Not looks so dynamically/ magic by read those twin lines of code, but now I can even build a chess game, wow! :D